# Replace all content of file with the content of another file

Tags: linux, macos

Is there a way to replace all content of a file with the content of another file without destroying the first file?

If I have a file in the current directory called `myfile.txt`, if I do the following:

`cp updatedfiles/myfile.txt myfile.txt`

then my old file is deleted and replaced with a new file (with the same name). I do not want to delete the existing file, I just want to change the content of the file. How to do this?

Comment: `cat updatedfiles/myfile.txt > myfile.txt`?

Comment: What is the difference between changing the content and deleting it to create it again? Or maybe you want to append the other file in the old one?

Comment: I do not want to append, I want to totally replace all content. Another system I am using depends on this (it gives me problems if there is a new file with the same name).

Comment: @DusanBajic, checked, worked :) If you put that in an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat updatedfiles/myfile.txt > myfile.txt
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks :)